# Determine which Monotouch.Dialog Checkbox was checked/unchecked

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a list of people that I want to display with checkboxes next to their names.  When an CheckBoxElement (person) is checked or unchecked, I need to handle the event.

```
        List<CheckboxElement> cbPersonElements = new List<CheckboxElement> ();
        CheckboxElement tmpCheckbox = new CheckboxElement ("");
        foreach (ABPerson itemPerson in _people) {
            tmpCheckbox = new CheckboxElement (itemPerson.LastName);
            cbPersonElements.Add(tmpCheckbox);
        }
```

And then I add the list when I create the RootElement:

```
        RootElement _rootElement = new RootElement ("People List"){
            new Section ("People"){
                cbPersonElements
        }
```

How should I add a handler that will allow me to detected which CheckBoxElement was clicked.

I can't attach one to tmpCheckbox, that value changes with each iteration through the loop.
Seems like it should be simple, but I can't see it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use a ValueChanged handler

```
foreach (ABPerson itemPerson in _people) {
  tmpCheckbox = new CheckboxElement (itemPerson.LastName);
  tmpCheckbox.ValueChanged += delegate {
    // do something here based on tmpCheckbox.Value
  };
  cbPersonElements.Add(tmpCheckbox);
}
```

Comment: It looks like ValueChanged might have been depreciated. Or, do I need to cast the CheckboxElement to something else. As is, the compiler reports "Type Monotouh.Dialog.CheckboxElement does not contain a definition for 'ValueChanged' and no extension method ..."

Comment: Sorry - looks like Bool & Entry elements have it, but not checkboxes.  Your best bet might be to create a custom Checkbox element that implements it, and also file a bug with Xamarin to correct this.